# How to count unique values in one column based on two separate columns in sheets

Tags: google-sheets, filter, unique, counting, countif

[image: sample data]

For each account, I want the total number of unique customers that purchased "Tech1." My data is on one tab and the unique account list is on another.

I can get the number of rows that match the account and contain "Tech1" with this: `=countifs($A$2:$A$30,$E2, $C$2:$C$30,"*Tech1*")` But I can't figure out how to count each customer that contains the target product only once.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try

```
=COUNTUNIQUE(IFERROR(FILTER(B:B, A:A="xxx", REGEXMATCH(C:C, "Tech1"))))
```

[image: 0]

Comment: Thanks player0! This is SOO close. This gives me either the right answer or a 1. if you add a customer yyy that doesn't have tech1 purchases, you'll get 1 as the result instead of 0.

Comment: @ChrisRosendin fixed, try now